Как отключить зум яндекс карты при скроле страницы в api 3.0
Подскажите вариант решения вопроса, если можно с примером кода. Нужно отключить зум яндекс карты при скроле страницы, но при этом он должен работать при клике на карту. Также желательно, чтобы функция выполнялась и в мобильной версии.
Вариант используемый для api 2.1 не работает (карта не выводится вообще), через
scrollZoom: false
       });
    map.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');
    map.events.add('click', function(e) {
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1, {center: e.get('coords')}); 


Нужно указать поведения в behaviors. Пример:
const map = new YMap(document.getElementById(mapID),{
location: {
center: coords,
zoom: zoom
},
behaviors: ['drag', 'pinchZoom', 'dblClick']
});

Большое спасибо за подсказку, теперь работает без нареканий!

Собрали пример, где карта отображается и достигается необходимое поведение карты. В мобильной версии вы можете выполнять скролл вне области блока карты. Если же необходим скролл страницы при скролле в блоке карты, вы можете отключить поведение drag. При отключённом drag страница сайта пролистывается так, как будто карта — это изображение.

Спасибо за ответ, но вижу, что в примере используется API 2.1. В моем случае используется именно 3 версия. Я так понимаю, что код в них не взаимозаменяем...
